# Using SSM Parameter Store with a Containerised Spring Boot running on EC2 through ECS

Tags: spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-ssm

I've been working on containerising an application with the intention of using ECS to manage the creation and deployment of the application to EC2.

Guides I've followed include:

[The Spring guide for containerising applications](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)

[Deploying Spring Boot on ECS](https://mydeveloperplanet.com/2021/09/07/how-to-deploy-a-spring-boot-app-on-aws-ecs-cluster/)

[A guide on adding Parameter Store](https://towardsaws.com/how-to-externalize-spring-boot-properties-to-an-aws-system-manager-parameter-store-2a945b1e856f)

[Another guide on adding Parameter Store](https://rieckpil.de/resolving-spring-boot-properties-using-the-aws-parameter-store-ssm/)

This hasn't panned out entirely, and I believe I've narrowed it down to the Parameter Store config as the source of the issue.

Right now, `pom.xml` is pretty light-touch, though I've seen more config needed depending on the scenario:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Running locally, outside of a container, I can access parameters with very minimal bootstrap config:

```
spring.application.name=PxTest
#I would usually provide this...
#cloud.aws.credentials.profile-name=default
#...but it seems like Spring assumes this.
```

As soon as I containerise it, it fails. I then added:

```
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1
cloud.aws.region.auto=false
```

As I understand it, this *should* help Spring find the appropriate parameters - but I've seen very little in the way of documentation or articles describing passing SSM Parameter Store properties into a Spring Boot application running on an ECS-provisioned EC2.

The error messages I can access on the EC2 talk about Docker entering promiscuous state, followed by blocking state, and repeating. Given it works fine without SSM, I suspect this is the Spring application starting up, failing, and then being retriggered repeatedly.

Running locally, the errors I get are:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint:
(short version, at EC2ResourceFetcher readResource)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Factory method 'ssmClient' threw Exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.
```

And then a knock-on exception about not being able to instantiate beans because it can't get to the SSM service.

As above, I am providing a region in bootstrap.properties but it seems to be ignoring this locally - but as it will be part of an application stack when deployed, it seems unlikely to me that it'll be the same error locally that is seen on AWS?

Has anyone accomplished this before, or have any resources which may be useful on what information I need to pass into the container to allow it to talk to SSM?

Comment: I've done this before, but on Fargate instead of EC2. Please edit your question to add the error message you are seeing. Does the ECS task have an IAM role that gives it permission to access the parameter store? Any reason you are using this Spring library instead of the ECS built-in support for injecting secrets from Parameter Store? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-data-security-container-task/

Comment: Thankyou for your reply - I'll edit and add the exception in a second. I'll try adding a parameter store IAM role, seems obvious enough for it to be the answer! I've been trying to get the Spring library to work because then I have the ability to pass in an arbitrary number of parameters, as long as they're defined in Parameter Store, rather than having to amend the task definition every time. Although I'd have to amend Parameter Store every time. So maybe...maybe it's not so bad.

Comment: I've ended up rejigging the application to use the ECS secret injection functionality - for the amount of work involved I'm not sure it's worth trying to get the spring library to work. The dearth of documentation on getting said library to work in a container suggests to me that it's not an expected use case. Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [the built-in support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-data-security-container-task/) ECS has for injecting secrets from SSM Parameter Store (or Secrets Manager) as environment variables. That way your code is more environment agnostic, and you can run it locally by just setting environment variables instead of connecting it to an external dependency like SSM Parameter Store.